# Connect via wpa_supplicant from Lua Application and .sh scripts

Tags: linux, lua, buildroot, wpa-supplicant

On my devices since a few months we have installed WiFi modules, from user interface you can scan available wifi networks and connect to one of them.
If the connection is successful I store data about that connection to make it possible to automatically reconnect at a later device startup.

My UI application is ralized in LUA and from code I have the ability to run linux commands (I work in Buildroot environment), for various reasons I don't have connman available so I manage the network connection with *wpa_supplicant*.

Currently let's say my solution is pretty lousy, it works but it certainly can't be called a good job.

I will try to summarize it quickly:
Every 10 seconds I update the list of available networks with the command

```
iwlist wlan0 scan
```

then I update the list of available wifi and their characteristics.
In parallel I have another routine (Lua) that every 5 seconds checks the connection status, if the connection is established OK, otherwise it tries to establish a connection with one of the stored networks.
To establish a connection I use wpa_supplicant, the problem is that wpa_supplicant is not instantaneous and I need some time frame (variable) to understand if the connection has been established or not.

the portion of code that manage this part is the following:

```
if(counter_500ms % 10 == 0 )then
    local file = io.open("/tmp/connesso","r")
    if(not(file)) then
        Connesso_A_Internet = false
    else
        local lettura = tonumber(file:read("*a"))
        file:close()
        if(lettura == 1)then
            print("connesso")
            Connesso_A_Internet = true
            Tempo_Last_Check_Connection = gre.mstime() / 1000
        else
            if(Connesso_A_Internet and math.abs(Tempo_Last_Check_Connection - gre.mstime() / 1000) >= 20)then
                Connesso_A_Internet = false
                First_Connection_Wifi(mapargs)
            elseif(Connesso_A_Internet and math.abs(Tempo_Last_Check_Connection - gre.mstime() / 1000) < 10)then
                Connesso_A_Internet = true
            else
                Connesso_A_Internet = false
                if( math.abs(Tempo_Last_Check_Connection - gre.mstime() / 1000) >= 20)then
                    First_Connection_Wifi(mapargs)
                end
            end
            
        end
    end
end

-----
function First_Connection_Wifi(mapargs)
    -- enter only if internet connection is not present
    if(not Connesso_A_Internet)then
        local index = 0
        local f,p
        local nome_temp = nil
        -- parse the structure that contains information about available internet connection
        for i=1,#struttura_reti do
            local stringa_da_cercare = struttura_reti[i].name
            -- extract the ssid of available connections
            stringa_da_cercare = string.gsub(stringa_da_cercare," ","\\ ")

            -- check if this ssid has been used in the past
            local file = io.open("/mnt/tables/wpa_supplicant_"..stringa_da_cercare..".conf","r")
            if(not(file)) then
                -- this ssid has never been used in the past
                -- it seems that in this case a [sh] process is addes to ps output
                print("non c'è file", struttura_reti[i].name)
            else
                -- this ssid has never been used in the past since I have a .conf file with connection information
                print("c'è il file ->",struttura_reti[i].name)
                nome_temp = struttura_reti[i].name
                file:close()
                break
            end
        end

        -- if I found a ssid in memory I try to connect to this network
        -- since the connection is established, the [sh] problem is solved
        if(nome_temp ~= nil)then
            os.execute("killall wpa_supplicant &")

            gre.timer_set_timeout(function()
                Tempo_Last_Check_Connection = gre.mstime() / 1000
                Rete_In_Connessione = nome_temp
                local stringa_da_cercare = nome_temp
                stringa_da_cercare = string.gsub(stringa_da_cercare," ","\\ ")
                os.execute("wpa_supplicant -B -D nl80211 -i wlan0 -c /mnt/tables/wpa_supplicant_"..stringa_da_cercare..".conf &")
            end,500)
        end
    end
end
```

To understand if the connection is established I run the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
FirstIP="8.8.8.8" #(Google public DNS)
SecondIP="8.8.4.4" #(OpenDNS public DNS)
IDX="208"
DomoIP="192.168.1.103"
DomoPort="8080"

pingo="ping -c 5 -w 1 -q "$FirstIP"";
if $pingo | grep -E "min/avg/max" > /tmp/OutputPing;
then
    echo "1" > /tmp/connesso
else
    #echo "--> No response from first IP ("$FirstIP"), now trying second one ("$SecondIP")"
      pingo="ping -c 5 -w 1 -q "$SecondIP"";
      if $pingo | grep -E "min/avg/max" > /tmp/OutputPing;
      then
      echo "1" > /tmp/connesso

   else
      echo "0" > /tmp/connesso
   fi
fi
```

By checking the value of /tmp/connection I am able to determine whether the connection has been established or not.
Now, since this solution works but seems quite idiotic, how can I use wpa_supplicant more intelligently?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to not restart `wpa_supplicant` all the time, but instead use [`wpa_cli`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/wpa_cli) to dynamically reconfigure it.

`wpa_cli` connects to a socket that `wpa_supplicant` listens on - instead of using `wpa_cli`, you can also connect to this socket directly from your Lua code. That gives you a bit more flexibility.

To be able to use either `wpa_cli` or the sockets, you need to enable this during the build. Use the Buildroot option `BR2_PACKAGE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_CLI` for this (it automatically enables `BR2_PACKAGE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_CTRL_IFACE` which is what you need to listen on the socket).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, using wpa_cli shuold be a better solution.
Using only ping does not let me know whether the connection to the AP was successful or not, it only tells me whether the machine is connected to the Internet or not. If I use wpa_cli on the other hand, I am able to tell if the connection was successful; to check for internet connection instead I will continue to use ping, but only after checking that the connection to the router is ok.
Regarding lua instead, how can I check the socket connection from lua code?